# How to setup free shipping multiple store view

Tags: module, extensions, shipping-methods

I have 2 store view Suisse (ch) and France (fr) :

free shipping par store view 20 in fr and 30 in ch

I have found a extention fro flate rate : Magento 2 Multiple Shipping Flat Rates extension

there's any extension for free shipping

It's magento version 2.3.5-p1 (oppen source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can use magento free shipping for both countries or you can use magento table rates method **

[table rates](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html)

[free shipping](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/shipping-free.html)